# How to test Web Service calls through Junit

Tags: java, web-services, junit

I would like to test my web service using Junit. Once we missed the `public` modifier and it failed. So, to avoid such issue in the earlier stage we would like to write Junit test cases to test the web service connection.

I tried this but did not work.

```
String url = "http://localhost:port/webservice/path";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet( url );

request.setHeader("username", "user1");
HttpResponse httpResponse = 
HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     result.append(line);
}

My web service will be like this
```

```
@Path("/path") 
public interface WebServiceTest
{
   //list of services
}
```

I should get to know whether my call is success or failure through Junit test case.
How to implement it? Any other suggestions other than Junit but It should be through Java (No Mockito)?

EDIT: I need this for both SOAP and REST web services.

Comment: If you want to test a web-service as a client of it, maybe REST Assured is your choice for Java? I think writing `HttpConnection` code in pure JUnit is too much low-level overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use RestAssured. Using a method like this and pass the appropriate values.

```
 public static ResponseBody callAPI(String host, String body, String path, String method, Map<String,String> headers){
        RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();

        requestSpecBuilder.addHeaders(headers);
        requestSpecBuilder.setBody(body);
        requestSpecBuilder.setBaseUri(host);

        RequestSpecification requetSpecification = requestSpecBuilder.build();
        requestSpecBuilder.setContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        Response rs = null;
        if(method.equals("DELETE")){
            rs  = RestAssured.given(requetSpecification).when().log().all().delete(path);
        }else if(method.equals("POST")){
            rs  = RestAssured.given(requetSpecification).when().log().all().post(path);
        }

        return rs.getBody();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will check this. Can you also give me suggestions for SOAP testing?

Comment: I want to verify whether web service call is hitting particular api or not. Like verify() method in Mockito. Is there any way in Ret Assured?  I need this feature because my api will return different responses based on data, it can be success or some exception. So, I just want to check that api is being called or not.

Comment: You can try the do a GET call and if it retrieves a 200 then you are good.

Comment: like add this into the if block
else if(method.equals("GET")){
            rs  = RestAssured.given(requetSpecification).when().log().all().get(path);
        }